# Trigonometrical equation proving

Tags: trigonometry

$$s = I \cdot \cos x - Q \cdot \sin x$$
$$s=\frac{1}{\sqrt{I^2+Q^2})} \sin ( z-x),$$ where $$z=\cos^{-1}\frac{Q}{\sqrt{I^2+Q^2})} $$
I tried to get the second expression from first one begining,from deviding both sides by,$$\sqrt{I^2+Q^2})$$but couldn't get the second one, please anyone can help...

Answer (score 0):

I think, it should be
$$s=\sqrt{I^2+Q^2}\sin (z-x)$$

Answer (score 0):

$ s= I. \cos x - Q.\sin x$ ;

Multiply and divide by $ \sqrt{I^2+Q^2}$

$ s=\sqrt{(I^2+Q^2)} \ (\frac{I}{\sqrt{(I^2+Q^2)}} \cos x -\frac{Q}{\sqrt{(I^2+Q^2)}}\sin x) $

Now, $ \sin(A-B) =\sin A \cos B-\cos A\sin B $ .

Here, in our equation

$ B=x$ and

$A=z=\sin^{-1}\frac{I}{\sqrt{(I^2+Q^2)}} $ or  $A=z=\cos^{-1}\frac{Q}{\sqrt{(I^2+Q^2)}} $